# prerequisites for a server of spring boot, vaadin and mysql

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin-flow

I would like to make a linux server to host my application which is developed using spring boot, vaadin and mysql.
As far as I know jdk, Tomcat and mysql.

1. Though I am unsure if I also have to install maven and nodejs which I used in development.
2. Moreover where and how I have to install jdbc plus other libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that setup, the natural way would be to package the application as a .war file that is deployed to the Tomcat instance.

1. Maven and Node.js are needed to build the .war file when using Vaadin, but neither would be necessary just for using a pre-built .war. You can build the .war file on a separate machine. For simple operations you can do that on your own development machine but for anything more sophisticated it's recommended to use a "real" build system such as Jenkins or GitHub Actions.
2. JDBC itself is part of Java so nothing special is needed there. You also need to have the JDBC driver for MySQL, but that's just a .jar file that would be included in the .war file at build time based on what you've defined in your `pom.xml`. You thus don't need anything special on the server for that purpose.